# Python list into json format

Tags: python, json

Currently, I have a list as shown below.

```
List4 = ['4','6','9','10']

    finaldata = {  
   "animal":"cat",
   "type":[  
      {  
         "weight":"true",
         "origination":[  
            {  
               "number":"",
               "result":'',
            },
            {  
               "number":"",
               "result":,
            },
            {  
               "number":"",
               "result":,
            },
            {  
               "number":"",
               "result":,
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
finaldata.update({'result%s' % n:i for n,i in enumerate(list4)})

with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(finaldata, outfile)
```

I need to replace the values in list4 into "result" as shown below.
And replace the placement of value into the number.
So, first number is 4, so it'd be 1 in number, and 4 in result.
Second number is 6, so it'd be 2 in number, and 6 in result.

I'm having issue to put this in number/result field in actual, though I can update it in fields afterwards.

It could be larger than 4 items in a list.

```
{  
   "animal":"cat",
   "type":[  
      {  
         "weight":"true",
         "origination":[  
            {  
               "number":"1",
               "result":'4',
            },
            {  
               "number":"2",
               "result":6,
            },
            {  
               "number":"3",
               "result":9,
            },
            {  
               "number":"4",
               "result":10,
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON, your problem is just with how to update the list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update `finaldata['type']['origination']`, not `finaldata` itself. And it's a list, not a dictionary, so you can't use `.update()` for it (there are no keys like `result0` anywhere in `finaldata`). Just index it with the same index you get from `list4`.

```
origination = finaldata['type']['origination']
for i, result in enumerate(list4):
    origination[i]['number'] = str(i+1)
    origination[i]['result'] = result
```